# How to provide detailed listing of /tmp directory

Tags: macos, command-line

The standard options to `ls` are not working: I get the following

```
14:53:37/a2a $ls -l /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jan  9 14:16 /tmp -> private/tmp

$ls -lrta /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jan  9 14:16 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

The intent is to view  the contents of the directory, not the metadata info  it is a (hard?) link.

Note that `ls /tmp` does show the contents .. but not the detailed info like `last modified`

```
$ls /tmp
00f12e86-cfcc-4239-9dfc-006b65a319c3    com.symantec.symdaemon.launches
72f8fe65-e688-4d14-9aef-42c6abc1d4fa    exceptions.csv
835500b9-549b-435d-b444-97db8935fd88    ju.txt
 ..
com.symantec.avscandaemon.NF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `ls -l /tmp` shows /tmp is a symbolic link to private/tmp

So what you want is to replace tmp by what it is linked to e.g.

```
ls -l /private/tmp
```

or let ls do it for you using the -H option

```
ls -lH /tmp
```

`man ls` says

> -H      Symbolic links on the command line are followed.  This option is
>                assumed if none of the -F, -d, or -l options are specified.

which explains whey ls with no options does show the contents of the directory that is linked to.

Comment: thx could not remember that one i even tried `ls -lh` (lower case `h`)